# Content script for no-cookie embedded YouTube video

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to set content script to all embedded youtube video, so i use the tag in content script:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.youtube.com/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "app_player.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
```

Everything worked ok, but I see that, there two types of embedded YouTube videos: youtube.com/embed and youtube-nocookie.com. For the second one, my content script didn't work. How can I do?

The second case for embedded code as:

```
<video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" 
        style="width: 815px; height: 458px; left: 0px; top: 19.2813px;"
     src="blob:https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/85648de5-fa2c-4785-bc8c-1fdce53c8226">
</video>
```

Comment: The second snippet isn't inside iframe? If so, there's nothing to insert the content script into.  It's not clear what exactly didn't work. Be more specific.

Comment: No, it is inside iframe. You can see this https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/04/27/make-the-most-of-your-time-with-the-new-windows-10-update/?ICID=Windowscom1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the description right, but did you try this?

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.youtube.com/*",
                "*://*.youtube-nocookie.com/*" // <- This did not work?
            ],
            "css": [
                "app_player.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What he said ^^

Comment: Maybe you can send us a screenshot of the console of the embedded youtube-nocookie.com site?

Comment: This is the embedded video that I want to test: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/04/27/make-the-most-of-your-time-with-the-new-windows-10-update/?ICID=Windowscom1

Comment: What do you want to happen, and what happens instead? You didn't show us your code so we can't help you.

Comment: No, sorry. I know the reason. It is not caused manifest json for content script.

Comment: Just set up a test and it worked for me. Are you remembering to create the script with a inject, like this? :


var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('myfile.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};

Comment: I resolved this problem. Although your recommendation didn't help me to solve this. However, I mark yours as answer, because it is right to the above question :)